# angular: header included in Access-Control-Expose-Headers by the server does not appear in $http headers

Tags: angularjs

this is the header response from the server in chrome:
(as you can see ) the header I need (set-cookie) is includedin Access-Control-Expose-Headers but anyways I cannot find it in headers from $http.post

any idea???

```
headers = Object {server: "CouchDB/1.5.0 (Erlang OTP/R16B03)", content-type: "application/json", cache-control: "must-revalidate"}
```

Chrome response header:

> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:1841
>   Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Content-Type, Server, Set-Cookie
>   Cache-Control:must-revalidate Content-Length:37
>   Content-Type:application/json Date:Wed, 27 May 2015 14:56:27 GMT
>   Server:CouchDB/1.5.0 (Erlang OTP/R16B03)
>   Set-Cookie:AuthSession=anVhbjo1NTVFREE1ODqXz-CpdXZULeYYDAyHDY80iQuGGg;
>   Version=1; Path=/; HttpOnly